# Prediction for single image file using tensor flow transfer learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction, transfer-learning, image-classification

I am new to image classification and sorry if this problem seems too naive. I am using tf transfer learning model for my recent work. Ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning.

Here there is clear mention of how to use this model to prediction on batch prediction for images. But i am having a hard time figuring out how to do prediction for single image using this.

I tried with this:

```
np_image = Image.open(image_path)
np_image = np.array(np_image).astype('float32')/255
np_image = transform.resize(np_image, (800, 700, 3))
np_image = np.expand_dims(np_image, axis=0)
probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])
predictions = probability_model.predict_proba(np_image)
```

But this is giving 1 as result for all images. I want probability prediction at an image level using this model.

Comment: Used the exact same code as given in ref just changed the image dimension and the folder structure where i am reading the data to fit my problem statement and the whole notebook is working fine and giving correct predictions for batch data. But for singel images it not working

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution for this problem.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
image = load_img(image_path, target_size=(800, 700))


image = img_to_array(image)
image = image.reshape((1, image.shape[0], image.shape[1], image.shape[2]))
predictions = tf.nn.sigmoid(new_model.predict(image))
predictions=np.array(predictions)[0][0]
```